# Effective way to create on-the-fly arrays/hashes with ruby?

Tags: ruby

What I want to do is something like this:

```
arr = %w(good bad great dull)
"Today was a #{arr.sample} day"
```

Say I wanted to then loop this 100 times and count each sampled element, and collect the counters in a separate hash or array, how would I do that? And would this be better approached with a hash or an array?

Something like:

```
counter = []
arr.each { |el| counter << [el => 0] }

100.times do 
  el = arr.sample
  # lost here..
end
```

Output I want (array or hash):

```
["good" => 20, "bad" => 20, "great" => 40, "dull" => 20]
```

I also figure there is a more elegant solution to my first way of thinking.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Your title makes it seems like you want to create a one-off array/hash for playing with, but your body seems very far from that. Also your final output doesn't make any sense, it's an array with key/value pairs, but no hash delimiters.

Comment: Could you suggest a better title? I think the body clearly defines what I'm looking for. I want to iterate over and array and count the sampled elements, have them stored in an array OR hash - as in I don't know which would better suit this situation.

Comment: Btw, why `"#{el}"` and not just `el`? They're equivalent since `el` is already a string.

Comment: That's because I switched that particular code from hash to array to clarify based on your first comment. I'll edit also so I don't contribute to spreading terrible Ruby :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
arr = %w(good bad great dull)
counter = Hash.new(0)
100.times { counter[arr.sample] += 1 }
counter #=> {"great"=>22, "good"=>29, "bad"=>21, "dull"=>28}
```

You could also do:

```
arr = %w(good bad great dull)
(1..100).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |_, h| h[arr.sample] += 1 }
#=> {"great"=>22, "good"=>29, "bad"=>21, "dull"=>28}
```

which is a bit more "self-contained", and returns the hash itself instead of `100` like `times` does (though you could also use [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) to get that effect).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to create this hash during the iterator? I was thinking maybe the ||= might come in handy here, but I'm a little lost whether it is even possible.

Comment: @Zenph You would normally use [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), but you're not really iterating over anything here, just looping. I've updated my answer with a version using that.

Comment: While the 2nd solution is definitely cool, I think the 1st takes the cake for code readability

Comment: @Josh I agree, but the OP asked and code golf is always fun anyway `:)`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thanks. Just keeping you on your toes ;) You know your Ruby. I'll use the first solution, but I'll study the second.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are pretty close.  A hash makes perfect sense:

```
counter = Hash.new
arr.each { |el| counter[el] = 0  }

100.times do 
  counter[arr.sample] += 1
end
```